# How Can I show the hidden form again while the application is not a single instance?

Tags: c#, forms

In Windows forms,
On closing the form,instead of closing, I want to hide it and When I open the application again, if the form is already hidden, I want to show the hidden form.
If there is no opened form, then open new application.
The code what I wrote does not working correctly, because when I close the form, instead of opening the hidden form , it opens a new form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();               

    }      
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {

            e.Cancel = true;                
            this.Visible = false;

        }

        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown && e.CloseReason == CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

    } 




   static class Program
    {        
        static Form1 mainFrm; 

static void Main()
        {
            Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
            bool InstanceRunning = false;
            long runningId = 50000;
            foreach (Process p in runningProcesses)
            {
                try
                {
                    Mutex newinstanceMutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("Global\\MUTEXPIDBYCHYROPTERON" + p.Id.ToString());
                    try
                    {
                        newinstanceMutex.ReleaseMutex();
                    }
                    catch { }
                    InstanceRunning = true;
                    runningId = p.Id;
                    break;
                }
                catch { }
            }
            if (!InstanceRunning)
            {



                mainFrm = new Form1();
                Application.Run(mainFrm);
            }
            else
            {
                var cp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                string procName = cp.ProcessName;
                //get the list of all processes by that name

               Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName);

                if (processes.Length > 0)
                {
                    mainFrm.ShowDialog();
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: Would you like to add the code were people can see what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please add that code, maybe we can detect the problem

Comment: You need to call ShowDialgo in the Closed Application using some Inter Process Communication (like a named pip) not in the newly lunched process.

Comment: The Show() call must be made in the process that currently owns the hidden window.  In other words, you need process interop to let the other one know.  Luckily that is a wholeheckofalot simpler than it sounds, this feature is built into the framework: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it, it is working now

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
   static EventWaitHandle FocusProgram = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "FocusMyProgram198472");
    //private delegate void focusConfirmed(); Thread FocusCheck;
    private void focus()
    {
        FocusProgram.WaitOne();
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            this.Show();
            this.BringToFront();
        }));
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CloseReason)
        {
            case CloseReason.UserClosing:
                e.Cancel = true;
                FocusProgram.Reset();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) => focus()));
                Hide();
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void ShowHidden()
    {
        FocusProgram.Set();
    }
```

}

```
static class Program
    {
        private static Mutex me;
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            if (Exists())
            {
                Form1.ShowHidden();                              
                return;
           }            
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private static bool Exists()
        {
            var createdNew = false;
            me = new Mutex(true, "TestForm123545654", out createdNew);
            return !createdNew;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although it is agood way, I don’t think that opening another application to unhide the previous one is intuitive nor expected. Why is the original application hidden in the first place?